# VS2017 Open Folders - configure 'Compile C' context in tasks.vs.json?

Tags: c, visual-studio

With VS 2017, you have the option of `File->Open->Open Folder` to open all sources in the Solution Explorer without needing to create a project. Theoretically, this will allow you to work with any of the small single-source files in a directory to compile, debug, etc.. without needing to set up a project for each one. However, I have yet to find a way to add a working `'Compile'` option to the *Solution Explorer* context-menu that will invoke the compiler to build the individual files.

Microsoft provides several reference pages aimed at explaining the process:

- [Develop code in Visual Studio without projects or solutions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/develop-code-in-visual-studio-without-projects-or-solutions)
- [Open Folder projects for C++](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/ide/non-msbuild-projects)
- [Developer Command Prompt for Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/developer-command-prompt-for-vs)

This has been tangentially touched on in the SO question [VS2017 'Open Folder'-project fails to generate CMake cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50548274/vs2017-open-folder-project-fails-to-generate-cmake-cache) though that is limited to `cmake` specifically and ended up being a typo in the questioners attempt to follow [CMake support in Visual Studio](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2016/10/05/cmake-support-in-visual-studio/#configure-cmake)

The problem I am having is when I add a *task* to `tasks.vs.json` to compile the C files in a directory, VS responds with an error in the message window that `cl cannot be found as an internal or external command`. The `tasks.vs.json` task I am attempting to use is:

```
{
  "version": "0.2.1",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "taskName": "Echo filename",
      "appliesTo": "*.c",
      "type": "command",
      "command": "${env.COMSPEC}",
      "args": ["cl /nologo /W3 /wd4996 /Ox /Foobj/ /Febin/${fileBasename} /Tc ${file}"]
    },
    {
      ... (normal default entries for launch...)
    }
  ]
}
```

The *inherited environments* for `msvc_x86` and `msvc-x64` for both "Debug" and "Release" are properly created by default in the directory within `CppProperties.json`.

I have attempted to create an external tool for the VS Command Prompt through `Tools->External Tools... Add` and launching `cmd.exe` with `/k "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 17.0\Common7\Tools\VsDevCmd.bat"` (which opens the desired developer command line just fine), but does not provide an external command to which to pass the compile string to compile a source file from the Solutions Explorer list.

I simply want to invoke the `cl.exe` compiler on the file selected in the Solution Explorer list with the following command line:

```
cl /nologo /W3 /wd4996 /Ox /Foobj/ /Febin/${fileBasename} /Tc ${file}
```

I may be reading the documentation wrong, but how do you craft a task entry in `tasks.vs.json` (or elsewhere) that will provide a simple context-menu entry to allow compiling the C-sources opened with `File->Open->Open Folder`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Customize build and debug tasks for "Open Folder" development](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/customize-build-and-debug-tasks-in-visual-studio), this works.

```
{
  "version": "0.2.1",
  "tasks": [
    {
        "taskName": "cl-task",
        "appliesTo": "*.c",
        "type": "command",
        "command": "cl",
        "args": [ "${file}" ],
        "envVars": {
            "VSCMD_START_DIR": "\"${workspaceRoot}\""
        }
    }
  ]
}
```

`CppProperties.json` provides information for browsing, that is for IntelliSense behavior.

To specify environment variables, use `envVars` instead. You can create a file `VSWorkspaceSettings.json` in the root folder and add

```
{
    "envVars": { "PATH": "%PATH%;C:\\Users\\zhaofeng-shu33\\Anaconda3\\Scripts" }
}
```

Then the following task will work. It simply outputs help message for program `conda`, which is an executable located within folder `Scripts` and is not added to the global environment variable.

```
{
    "taskName": "conda-task",
    "appliesTo": "*.c",
    "type": "command",
    "command": "${env.COMSPEC}",
    "args": [ "conda --help" ]
}
```

Comment: This does indeed work. Thank you. It's rather funny that VS puts a squiggly underline under the `"type"` entry and a pop-up that says `Value must be on of the following values "default", "launch", "msbuild" or "remote"` (this is odd, given it is contrary to Microsoft's own examples given in the links above...) I used `/nologo /W3 /wd4996 /Ox /Foobj/ /Febin/${fileBasename} /Tc ${file}` as the `args": [...]` content. Works fine.